# 2002 explorer anti theft light

Tags: ford, security, explorer

I have a 2002 ford explorer. I drove it yesterday no problems. Went to start it today and the key won't even turn in the ignition. The theft light is blinking.  I've tried disconnecting the battery and that's not working.  Is there any way to disable the anti theft as I don't have money to go to a dealership

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a different key? If the key isn't turning, it's not the fault of the anti-theft, it's a mechanical problem with the key and locking mechanism. The security light is going to flash until you are able to turn the key in the ignition. You may try jiggling the steering wheel a little and see if that will allow the key to turn.

Answer (score 0):

Well, did you steal it? :D

Unfortunately, you have to take your car to a certified locksmith who works on cars or to the dealership. These anti theft system has codes unique to your vehicle only dealer and locksmith has access to.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the light blinking and nothing else put a cute little sticker over it.    I can't get mine to stop either same thing with the key I just keep turning the key over and shaking the wheel.  Bought a unavural remote at auto zone  for 20bucks it locks and unlocks my doors and works the alarm system  but that damn light still blinks all the time.   Good luck